# Making calls to Azure Devops API endpoints from a 3rd party server

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a project where:

1. I create/add a label on an issue at a Github Repo.
2. Github initiates a call to my server via webhooks.
3. I do some stuff backend, and if ok decide to make a call to Azure Devops to open a card.

My question is the 3rd step. I looked through the [REST API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) / [authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops), but I cannot find anything related to authenticating from a 3rd party server.

Any idea/documentation or even using a third party app solution to bypass (Github -> My server -> Some other 3rd party app -> Azure) is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take look here - [Authenticate access with personal access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). With PAT token you can call to REST API form wherever you want, powershell, postman etc.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: So  if I am not mistaken I make the REST API call and add the HTTP Authorization Basic header : `Authorization: Basic base64(username:PAT)` Would that work?